# Windows Sever 2000 machine with striped scsi disk to VHD

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, vhd, physical-to-virtual, windows-2000

Currently have a lot of servers running legacy applications that only work with W2k running on very old hardware that needs to be replaced.

The plan is to convert each current machine into a VHD and then import the VHD into W2k8 server using Hyper-V

I have managed to p2v w2k offline using the sysinternals Disk2VHD tool with servers that weren't using raid or scsi disks they only had standard hard drives with sata connections.

I disconnected hard drive from the server and used a sata to usb cable along & sata power to ac power adapter and then plugged the usb into a different machine running windows 7 started Disk2VHD tool selected the partitions of the server running w2k and created and did an offline conversion. - That was pretty seamless and really easy.

**The real issue**
 I am having is with some HP servers that are RAIDED striped across two scsi disks into one logical drive I cannot seem to actually convert them to VHD successfully, I have previously used VMware converter and got a .VMDK of one of the servers and tried it on ESXi but it would BSOD - Inaccessible_boot_device 0x0000007B.

If I can get it running in Hyper-V First time I would prefer to do that also If I could use the VMware Converter and then convert between VMDK and VHD that would be a good.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use vmware converter and after import the image in hyperv.

Vmware converter do a great job for the p2v by adding the scsi driver, and hyperv do a good job to import such image.